# Does "shut off the water" mean to just turn off the tap or to stop the whole water system in your house?

Tags: word-usage, american-english, british-english

A [British native English speaker](https://www.quora.com/I-often-hear-people-say-turn-off-the-tap-and-shut-off-the-water-Is-it-common-to-say-turn-off-the-water-and-shut-off-the-tap/answer/Elizabeth-Henderson-40?__filter__=all&__nsrc__=notif_page&__sncid__=40940191188&__snid3__=54809434542) said

> In the UK at least, we “shut off” the water when we want to work on
> the plumbing and need to know that the water from the mains won’t keep
> flowing and flooding the kitchen.
>
> We turn taps on and off. If we talk about shutting off the water, it
> means we’re turning the stop-cock to stop the entire water supply to
> the house.

Does "**shut off the water**" mean to just turn off the tap or to stop the whole water system in your house?

Comment: Doesn't the second paragraph of text that you quoted explain the answer?

Comment: Anecdotally, I've heard the phrase used for both situations (AmE, NYC area); the meaning is contextually dependent.

Comment: In the US also, we shut off the water. It means you are closing the valve that lets water flow into the pipes.

Comment: In my part of Canada, probably pretty representative of North America, the individual tap usually gets "turned off", while the main valve gets "shut off".

Comment: "Shut off" in the sense of "turn off" is not a very common expression in British English; so if it used in this way it would be far more likely to mean turning off the water to the whole house than one pipe.

Comment: @ColinFine That is true in AmE as well. It means no water is getting through the mains.

Answer (score 2):

**Usually yes, but it depends on context.**

With no other context "shut off the water" probably means to turn off the water to an entire house, and you would use "turn off the tap" to ... well, turn off the tap. But in other contexts it might not. For example of you are washing a car or watering a garden with a hosepipe then "shut off the water" would probably mean to turn off the water flow to the hosepipe. Likewise if you discover that a bathtub has been left running and is overflowing you might want to "shut off the water" which just means to stop the bathtub filling. (You would say "shut off the mains" to unambiguously shut off the house water supply)